# How to store list of center points from last frame for comparing current frame's list of center points

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, object-detection

I need to compare previous frame's lists with current frame's lists. I'm able to store and print the current frame's lists from get_contours function. It appends center points of detected objects from video to empty lists called whiteCoordinates and otherCoordinates.

Problem is, I don't know how to store previous frame's whiteCoordinates and otherCoordinates lists. I have tried different loops and such but always get current frame's center points for both lists. Next iteration always wipes the previous frame's lists to same as current.

So how it could be done? How could I store previous lists to whiteCoordinates2 and otherCoordinates2 and use them to compare with current frame's lists whiteCoordinates and otherCoordinates.

```
# returns every center point from video's objects to a list.
whiteCoordinates = []   #empty lists
otherCoordinates = []
def get_contours(hsv, target, mask):
    cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    cnts = imutils.grab_contours(cnts)

    for contour in cnts:
        if filter_contours(contour):
            try:
                M = cv2.moments(contour)
                cX = int(M["m10"] / M["m00"])   #returns center points
                cY = int(M["m01"] / M["m00"])
                cv2.circle(target, (cX,cY), 5, (0, 0, 255), -1)
                mcolor = mean_color(hsv, contour)
                if colour_filter(mcolor):
                    cv2.putText(target,"White %s" % mcolor.astype(np.int), (cX, cY), font, 0.5, fontColor, lineType=lineType)
                    whiteCoordinates.append((cX, cY))   #appends center points to list
                else:
                    cv2.putText(target,"Other %s" % mcolor.astype(np.int), (cX, cY), font, 0.5, fontColor, lineType=lineType)
                    otherCoordinates.append((cX, cY))   #appends center points to list
            except:
                pass

    return target
```

```
while True:
    #how to store previous lists to otherCoordinates2, whiteCoordinates2
    whiteCoordinates2, otherCoordinates2 = whiteCoordinates, otherCoordinates
    #convert to tuples
    firstOther = set(map(tuple, otherCoordinates))
    secOther = set(map(tuple, otherCoordinates2))
    firstWhite = set(map(tuple, whiteCoordinates))
    secWhite = set(map(tuple, whiteCoordinates2))
#check lenght of diffecences, if 0 nothing have moved  
    other = len(firstOther.symmetric_difference(secOther))
    white = len(firstWhite.symmetric_difference(secWhite))
    hits = 0
    miss = 0
#calculates is others have moved
    if other != 0:
        hits += 1
    else:
        miss += 1
    print(miss, hits)
    print(firstOther, secOther)
```

Desired outcome is to compare previous and current lists for detecting if there have been movement between frames. Does this make any sense to anyone? Thank you for even reading this, special thanks if someone has any tips!

Link for full code: https://github.com/kristiansyrjanen/billystat/blob/master/matias/circles/palloframe.py

Answer (score 0):

`whiteCoordinates2 = whiteCoordinates` doesn't copy the list, it copies the reference to the list in memory. Therefor any change to either will also appear in the other.

To make a proper copy of the list you can use `whiteCoordinates2 = whiteCoordinates.copy()`